# Set up a pipeline that triggers either on branch or tag, but not both

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can configure my pipeline to:

1. Trigger when a commit is pushed to `main`
2. OR, when a version tag is pushed

AND only trigger one pipeline when I push the new version commit and tag.

I'm using `npm version <version-bump>` followed by `git push --follow-tags` to kick off my pipeline. The trigger is configured as shown below:

```yaml
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  tags:
    include:
      - v*
```

However, after pushing the version commit and tag, Azure starts two pipelines, one triggered by the commit on `main`, the other one by the new `v*` tag.

For the record, this configuration gives me the same result:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
      - refs/tags/*
```

I would prefer to configure Azure to, in case of a version tag, only trigger one pipeline.

Is this possible using only one pipeline definition? Am I misunderstanding how triggers are supposed to work together? Any help greatly appreciated.